# How to stagger children with Framer Motion in a separate file?

Tags: reactjs, children, framer-motion

I am trying to stagger a list of children `div's` that are rendered in a separate component from the div that holds them.

Is this an issue of the parent-child relationship not being in the same file?

Here is the structure:

```
Games.js (Parent)
GameItem.js (Child)
```

```js
// Games
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

export const Games = () => {

// Framer Motion Animation
const container = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    show: {
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        staggerChildren: 0.5,
      },
    },
  }

// Render child items
const gameItems = games.map((game, index) => (
  <GameItem
    key={index}
    game={game}
    index={index}
  />
))

return (
 <motion.div
    variants={container}
    initial="hidden"
    animate="show"
  >{gameItems}
 <motion.div>
)}
```

```js
// GameItem.js

import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

// Framer Motion Animation
const item = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0 },
  show: { opacity: 1 },
}

return (
    <motion.div
      variants={item}
    >{game.name}</motion.div>
)}
```

Comment: Overall seems to be fine https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-directional-stagger-effect-grid-forked-4qwyd . There is a small issue in your `Games` though, closing `<motion.div>` needs to have forward slash to close the element `</motion.div>`